# WebView white screen

Tags: android, android-activity, webview

I have a problem with my WebView and I don't know how fix it. Before added the WebView, I had a ListView, now I have only a white screen when I launch the activity. Can you help me to fix it please ?

Here the XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<WebView
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
<ListView
android:id="@+id/lvMods"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And my Java file :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;


public class Mods extends Test {
        private ListView lvMods;

        @Override

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.listemods);

        lvMods = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvMods);

        String[] listeStrings = {"1","2","3","4"};

        lvMods.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listeStrings));
        lvMods.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                    CallFunc(position);
                }

                        private void CallFunc(int position) {
                                WebView wvpdf = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
                                wvpdf.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                switch (position) {
                  case 0:
                         wvpdf.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
                  break;
                  case 1 :
                         wvpdf.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
                  break;
                  case 2 :
                         wvpdf.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
                break;
                  case 3 :
                         wvpdf.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
                }
                        }
                });
        }}
```

Note : in my manifest I have Internet permissions

Thank you very much

Comment: what is that listemod layout.. u have designed it..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting layout:height="fill_parent"webview as fillparent make it as layout_height="wrap_content". Because if you do webview as fill parent then you cannot see listview. I have set minimum:height and background color those are not mandatory.

Donot forget to vote my answer. If it is useful for you.

Thanks

Deepak

Please find the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<WebView
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#000000"
android:minHeight="60dip"
/>
<ListView
android:id="@+id/lvMods"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
>
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried your modification and it's work !

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `fill_parent` to all `View`s.. Try using weight instead to manage the proportion of the layout...